# Must declare the scalar variable of @telefoonnummer?

Tags: c#

Everytime i am trying to insert data into two tables the first tables gets the data but the contact data remains empty and gets an error: Must declare the scalar variable of @telefoonnummer??

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nickd\documents\VB\killerapp\killerapp\CVNeetKompleet.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlCommand CmdSql = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Ledenlijst] (Voornaam, Achternaam, Adres, HuisNr, Postcode, Woonplaats, Geboortedatum) VALUES (@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Adres, @HuisNr, @Postcode, @Woonplaats, @Geboortedatum)", conn);

                conn.Open();
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaam", tbInvoer.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam", tbAchternaam.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adres", tbAdres.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HuisNr", tbHuisNummer.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", tbPostcode.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Woonplaats", tbWoonplaats.Text);
                CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geboortedatum", tbGeboortedatum.Text);
                CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand CmdSql2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Contact] (EmailAdres, Telefoonnummer) VALUES (@EmailAdres, @Telefoonnummer)", conn);
                CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdres", tbEmail.Text);
                CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefoonnummers", Convert.ToInt32(tbTelefoonnummer.Text));
                CmdSql2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Telefoonnummer Vs Telefoonnummers. By the way, why are you converting it to int? That will remove leading zeroes. That are important in phone numbers.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL query you have "@Telefoonnummer" but later when you assign the value you have it with `s` at the end

Remove the 's and it will work.

The correct should be like this:

```
CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefoonnummer", Convert.ToInt32(tbTelefoonnummer.Text));
```

Comment: There is a specific close reason for questions like these: _Simple typographical error not useful to future readers_

Comment: Steve: which one is that? "low quality"? I don't see close reason like the one you're mentioning

Comment: It is on the Off Topic list

Comment: @Steve ok, I didn't know there's another list after click on 'off topic'. Noted. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, your answer is correct and it helps the OP, I just add a simple comment to this kind of question

Comment: thanks for the aswer, sorry if the question was on the wrong topic, honestly i am new to this and working on a college assignment. I got stuck on this.